# Encoded Sequence Frames on Apple Product Pages

Tags: animation, sequence

I was looking through the source of the Apple product pages and found that they use encoded images for sequence animations (attached to the question), someone came across such an image format, how can they be used in their projects?
[encode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGzsy.jpg)

Comment: are you looking for some CSS trick or something else?

Comment: @RichárdBaldauf I want to understand how decoding such an image works